# trigonometry query

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin A - \cos A}{\sin A+\cos A}=\frac{X}{Y}$$
Then prove that $X^2 + Y^2 = 2$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since, we are told that x = sinA - cosA and y = sinA + cosA. Just simply sub that into  x^2+y^2=2 and do the algebra and use the Pythagorean THM and you will see that both sides are equivalent to one other.

Given: x = sinA - cosA, and y = sinA + cosA

Prove $x^2+y^2 = 2$

Pf:


LHS

$(sinA-cosA)^2 + (sinA+cosA)^2=$
$sin^2A-2sinAcosA+cos^2A+sin^2A+2sinAcosA+cos^2A$
= $(sin^2A+cos^2A)+(sin^2A+cos^2A) = 2$ [*Since, $sin^2x+cos^2x=1$]

$2=2$ $\checkmark$ Both Sides are equal

Comment: Where are we told that $x = \sin{A} - \cos{A}$ and $y = \sin{A} + \cos{A}$?

Comment: We get what x and y are from the rational provided in the question. You can see that on the left it the function and on the right it's the X.

Comment: Ah, I did not read $\sin A$ as a function, rather as a constant. I thought that you applied the same reasoning as $\frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{6} \Rightarrow 2 = 4$ and $3 = 6$. Still, I believe you are oversimplifying?

Comment: Oh, ok that happens sometimes but be careful when u read the expressions.

Comment: @Zero We are **not** told that $X=\sin A-\cos A$ and $Y=\sin A+\cos A$. The claim in the OP, as it is now, is actually incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I cant quite complete the exercise but this is what I did. I started rewriting the equation
$$Y= \sin A + \cos A , \ X=\sin A - \cos A$$
now $X^2+Y^2=(\sin A - \cos A)^2+ (\sin A + \cos A)^2$. This is
$$ (\sin A)^2 - 2 \sin A \cos A + (-\cos A)^2 + (\sin A)^2 + 2 \sin A \cos A + (\cos A)^2=2(\sin A)^2 + 2 (\cos A)^2 + \sin A \cos A (-2+2) = 2 (\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A) = 2$$